# best open source UML designing tool for n-ary relation

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm trying to choose a tool for creating UML diagrams, What is the best open source tool to create N-ary Relations of Association in Class Diagrams ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools

Comment: xmojmr, I don't search tools for Modeling Language but exactly the best tool to create N-ary Relations of Association in Class Diagrams.

Comment: you need to draw the `association class`? What do you mean by _best_?

Comment: easy tool to create ternary association uml (class diagram)

Comment: Your question is OT for SO. Please read SO's help on what kind of questions can be asked here.